# Best format for recording time stamp and GPS

Tags: data-formats, geospatial

In most data acquisition settings it is useful to tag your data with time and location. If I write the data to csv file, what are the best formats that I can use for this two variables if I want to create a heatmap on Google Maps?

Comment: "Best" is massively dependent on your application and probably subjective too.

Comment: Question was edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Spacedman put it, "best" is pretty subjective. However, as we have found, a good format for time is [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (aka POSIX time, aka Epoch time). Most databases support it and it is still pretty human readable.

For location, we like [decimal degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) as it is easy to read and stored and is compatible with Google Maps API. It's also easy to convert to other formats if needed.

Comment: If using decimal degrees make sure your metadata includes the Coordinate Reference System (most likely WGS84 lat-long, aka EPSG code 4326). Time stamps need to consider time zones, DST and leap seconds when applicable. Caveat emptor.